# Почему не выводит имя объекта через foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Данные получаю с формы. Почему не выводится имя ?

$user = new stdClass();
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->surName = $surName;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;
        foreach ($user as $key) {
            echo $key->name;
        }
Если так

```
foreach ($user as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

выводит все в одну строку. Как вывести все по отдельности? Вроде же должно работать echo $key->name echo $key->email; итд

Comment: с чего ты взял что должно работать echo $key->name echo $key->email; итд? на основе каких данных?

Comment: без цикла будет работать $user->name

Comment: Обратимся к документации ? [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Спасибо, я думал, что через foreach выводить нужно